# How make a button trigger a modal from an external component

Tags: javascript, components, bootstrap-modal, blazor

Hello i have a `modal` which at the moment gets `toggled` by a button.I want to toggle the modal from an external component but i want to keep this button in the template.

Can i from an external button redirect the click to this button and toggle the modal ?

**ModalComponent**

```
<div class="container">

     //I want this button to get triggered somehow from outside of component
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#campModal" data-toggle="modal"></button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="campModal" tabindex="-1" role="document">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Create</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <CampaignForm onclose="@this.OnClose" onsubmit="@this.OnSubmitAsync"></CampaignForm>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**External Source**

```
<div>
<button onclick="[trigger the button of the modal]"></button>
<Modal></Modal>
</div>
```

**P.S** What i need is the `ModalComponent` to keep its `button` as a Reusable component and somehow expose a parameter ,that when changed (from external component) triggers the modal.

I need basically to redirect a click from external component to the button inside the `ModalComponent`.(The modalbutton would be hidden)

Comment: Just give an id to the modal button (e.g: modal_but) and on the external button onclick=$("#modal_but").trigger('click')

Comment: How can i solve this with vanilla `js` ?

Comment: Something like this:
function triggerModal(){
 var elem = document.getElementById('modal_but');
    var event = new Event('click'); 
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
}

Comment: And then add triggerModal to the external button (onclick=triggerModal)

Comment: I made it work with `jquery` using `$(modalName).modal('toggle')` but with plain `javascript` it did not work.What would the equivalent in javascript be?

Comment: Hum... I've made you fiddle, and i think it works (I'm not testing the fact of being different files but it should be the same as long as the ModalComponent file is loaded first).
https://jsfiddle.net/9noetvyq/

Comment: Notes on the fiddle: Since you're using bootstrap (data-toggle/data-target), I see no reason why you can't use jquery (since you need it for bootstrap) . But, since you asked for vanilla js, I've adapted the code to vanilla, meaning I had to add a onclick for your button, and a style=display:none to your modal

Comment: You have tagged this with "Blazor" - if you are doing this in Blazor, please stop. The use of js to manipulate the dom is not supported and will likely break your application. I recommend you take a look at the community projects on blazor.net - they will help you to learn how to do this from C#